# Server error 500 on Django when deployed on Heroku when debug is set to False

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

Website is fine when debug is true, but when set to false it gives me a server error 500 evertime on every page.
When i go into heroku logs --tail
it tells me there is a status 500 issue.
I have set up my allowed host so that is not an issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the root of the issue could be?

Would appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: What do the heroku logs say? Does it show a stack trace? Just saying you are getting a 500 error is too broad to troubleshoot.

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBwhtEIXGII, was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True` in your setting.py. with this, you can see the errors in the log.

Secondly, the major cause to this error is usually the static files serving via whitenoise.
Run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic`, but before that make sure your STATIC_ROOT is correct.